# Convert comma-separated values into integer list in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

How to convert a comma-separated value into a list of integers in a pandas dataframe?

Input:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 steps - `split` and convert to integers, because after split values are lists of strings, solution working well also if different lengths of lists (not added `None`s):

```
df['qty'] = df['qty'].apply(lambda x: [int(y) for y in x.split(',')])
```

Or:

```
df['qty'] = df['qty'].apply(lambda x: list(map(int, x.split(','))))
```

Alternative solutions:

```
df['qty'] = [[int(y) for y in x.split(',')] for x in df['qty']]
df['qty'] = [list(map(int, x.split(','))) for x in df['qty']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try `expand=True`:

```
df['qty'] = df['qty'].str.split(',', expand=True).astype(int).agg(list, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Vectorised solution :

```
import ast

df["qty"] = ("[" + df["qty"].astype(str) + "]").apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Comment: `Vectorised solution` is not if use `apply` because `apply` are loops under the hoods.